# Could not GET gradle-0.14.4.pom - Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

After upgrading to Android Studio 1.0 I am no longer able to compiler my project.
I am getting an error saying “Failed to sync Gradle project 'Hello World' “.
Here is more information about this error:

```
Error:Could not GET'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.14.4/gradle-0.14.4.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request 
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

When I enable 'offline mode', it said “Failed to sync Gradle project 'Hello World' “ again.
More information about this:

```
Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

And after disabling 'offline mode' , previous error appears again.

Is there anyone has solved this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use older versions of Gradle anymore with Android Studio 1.0, I recommend you to upgrade your use of Gradle to 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Module :App) on Android Studio and change the following line:

```
runProguard false
```

for this one:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

That way you should be able to compile.